# How thoroughly can WINGS phases substitute for a flight review?

Tags: faa-regulations, far-61, faa-wings-program

If a pilot is unable to act as PIC because they need a flight review, can they instead earn WINGS credits and complete a phase? Everything I have read, including §61.56 and [AC 61-91J](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC%2061-91J.pdf), suggests that the answer is "yes", but apparently nobody else is discussing it because I can't seem to find the answer on the internet.

Answer (score 4):

All Wings courses that qualify for a Flight Review include both a online knowledge activites as well as required flight activities that are verified by a CFI. These flight requirements generally end up being longer than the 1 hr minimum flight time required by [§61.56](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library%5CrgFAR.nsf/0/EF04A9EEDC087ADF8625768F005C1BC3?OpenDocument).  But if you are completing a Wings course for the purpose of insurance discounts, a BRF would be a side benefit.

> To accomplish each Phase of WINGS, you can attend safety seminars,
>   take online courses, and demonstrate flight proficiency.

Also, section 1.3 of the [Wing Manual](https://www.faasafety.gov/documents/WINGS_Manual.pdf) states:

> Note that pilots need not accomplish the flight review requirements of
>   14 CFR part 
>   61.56, if he or she has satisfactorily completed any Phase in the WINGS - Pilot  Proficiency Program

So, the answer is yes, you can use Wings phases as a substitute for a flight review, but it might not be the most efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you still need a signoff from a CFI.  My group of friends (and my CFI) use wings.  I did that one year but I prefer flying the BFR because that's skill based.  I still do wings credit courses though; you can never learn too much.